# Como fazer um post usando Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Preciso criar um post no retrofit ao qual o envio siga este padrão, possuo cada classe em separado e uma classe `IDVerification` que contem todos juntos, e não sei de qual maneira monto este post

```
{
 "facebookProfile":{
  "name":"String",
  "education_history":"String",
  "birthday":"String",
  "hometown":"String",
  "email":"String",
  "location":"String"
},
 "picture":{
  "selfieURL":"String",
  "documentIDs":{
     "frontURL":"String",
     "backURL":"String"
      }
 }
}
```

IDVerification -

```
public class IDVerification {

    private FacebookProfile facebookProfile;

    private Picture picture;
}
```

exemplo de classe FacebookProfile - (Já contem getters e setters)

```
public class FacebookProfile implements Serializable{

    private String name;

    private String education_history;

    private String birthday;

    private String hometown;

    private String email;

    private String location;
}
```

Comment: Tem de ser mais especifico. Em que parte está a sua dificuldade? É na declaração da interface a passar ao *RestAdapter.Builder*?

Comment: sim, como criar certo a interface e como criar depois a chamada de maneira a passar cada parte certo

Comment: Eu preciso enviar para um servidor a informação contida em cada classe, e essas classes estão todas dentro desta IdVerification, quero saber de qual maneira eu declaro isso, e como eu faço para ir dividindo por classe para ficar algo proximo do exemplo que dei

Comment: Não basta ter um método na interface com `@POST` e um parâmetro com a anotação de `@Body`? Chegou a testar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dentro da interface

```
@POST("/data")
Call<IDVerification> postCustomerConfirmation (@Body IDVerification idVerification);
```

Dentro do onCreate da ActivityUI

```
Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIForid.base_url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Chamar uma classe de controle ou uso assíncrono

```
public void sendIDVerification(IDVerification idVerification) {
    sendIDVerificationUI.showSending();
    if(idVerification != null) {
        Call<IDVerification> call = apiForid.postCustomerConfirmation(idVerification);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<IDVerification>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<IDVerification> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    sendIDVerificationUI.finishSendingVerification();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                if(t.toString() != null) {
                    String message = t.getMessage();
                    if (message.contains("timeout") || message.contains("ETIMEDOUT")) {

                        sendIDVerificationUI.onSendIdVerificationError(0);

                    } else if (message.contains("Unable to resolve host")) {

                        sendIDVerificationUI.onSendIdVerificationError(0);

                    } else if (message.contains("Failed to connect")) {

                        sendIDVerificationUI.onSendIdVerificationError(0);

                    } else if (message.contains("SocketTimeout") ){

                        sendIDVerificationUI.onSendIdVerificationError(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Dentro da classe IDVerification criar um construtor

```
public IDVerification(FacebookProfile facebookProfile, Customer customer, Location location, Picture picture, Audio audio) {
    if(facebookProfile != null) {
        this.facebookProfile = new FacebookProfile(facebookProfile.getName(),
                facebookProfile.getEducation_history(),
                facebookProfile.getBirthday(),
                facebookProfile.getHometown(),
                facebookProfile.getEmail(),
                facebookProfile.getLocation());
    }
...
```

Dentro de cada classe usada anteriormente, ter seu próprio construtor

```
public FacebookProfile (String name, String education_history, String birthday, String hometown, String email, String location){
    this.name = name;
    this.education_history = education_history;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    this.hometown = hometown;
    this.email = email;
    this.location = location;
}
```